# Long time query execution in different same type sqlit3 database

Tags: sql, sqlite

## Situation

I have two sqlit3 database:

1. newsn3.db --> size: 122.229 kb

   - Table: Logs -> [Id: INTEGER, VariableId: INTEGER, Value: REAL, Timestamp: INTEGER]
   - Variables: Logs -> [Id: INTEGER, Name: TEXT, Timestamp: INTEGER]
2. oldsn3.db --> size: 1.800.000 kb

   - Table: Logs -> [Id: INTEGER, VariableId: INTEGER, Value: REAL, Timestamp: INTEGER]
   - Variables: Logs -> [Id: INTEGER, Name: TEXT, Timestamp: INTEGER]

And in both of them I run a query like this one:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TimestampLookup (
  TimestampStart bigint,
  TimestampEnd bigint,
  Category varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO TimestampLookup (TimestampStart, TimestampEnd, Category)
VALUES
--(638089367345448192, 638089367391931136, '1-1'),
--(638089368588500608, 638089368635085696, '2-1'),
--(638089423052093952, 638089423097359360, '3-1'),
--(638089424602983168, 638089424646700416, '4-1'),
--(638089426835122560, 638089426880267392, '5-1'),
--(638091321516003456, 638091321616836992, '6-1'),
--(638091346537689472, 638091346646865280, '7-1'),
(638108447105669629, 638108447105669851, '8-1');


SELECT Variables.Name, Logs.Timestamp, Logs.Value, TimestampLookup.Category
FROM Logs
JOIN Variables ON Logs.VariableId = Variables.Id
JOIN TimestampLookup ON Logs.Timestamp BETWEEN TimestampLookup.TimestampStart AND TimestampLookup.TimestampEnd
ORDER BY TimestampLookup.Category ASC, Logs.Timestamp ASC;
```

## Problem

As amazing as it is, the biggest size database "oldsn3.db" **runs the query in just 0.001 seconds.** But in the other hand, the small size database "newsn3.db" **runs the query in 2,5 seconds.**

## What could it be ...

- I don't really know how to deal with this situation. If someone experienced a similar situation and wants to share it will be fantastic.

### EDIT

1. As @NickW comment I run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN and this are the outputs:

   - "newsn3.db"

| id | parent | notused | detail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | SCAN Logs |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH Variables USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | SCAN TimestampLookup |
| 26 | 0 | 0 | USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY |

- "oldsn3.db"

| id | parent | notused | detail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | SCAN TimestampLookup |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH Logs USING INDEX idx_logs_timestamp (Timestamp>? AND Timestamp<?) |
| 18 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH Variables USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |
| 30 | 0 | 0 | USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY |

New query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TimestampLookup (
  TimestampStart bigint,
  TimestampEnd bigint,
  Category varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO TimestampLookup (TimestampStart, TimestampEnd, Category)
VALUES
--(638089367345448192, 638089367391931136, '1-1'),
--(638089368588500608, 638089368635085696, '2-1'),
--(638089423052093952, 638089423097359360, '3-1'),
--(638089424602983168, 638089424646700416, '4-1'),
--(638089426835122560, 638089426880267392, '5-1'),
--(638091321516003456, 638091321616836992, '6-1'),
--(638091346537689472, 638091346646865280, '7-1'),
(638089314046750888, 638089314046751656, '8-1');


EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT Variables.Name, Logs.Timestamp, Logs.Value, TimestampLookup.Category
FROM Logs
JOIN Variables ON Logs.VariableId = Variables.Id
JOIN TimestampLookup ON Logs.Timestamp BETWEEN TimestampLookup.TimestampStart AND TimestampLookup.TimestampEnd
ORDER BY TimestampLookup.Category ASC, Logs.Timestamp ASC;
```

Comment: Hi - are both databases running on identical infrastructure? Please run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for both queries and update your question with the outputs

Comment: @NickW I updated as you said. Thanks. :)

Comment: Do the Logs and Variables tables in both DBs have the same PKs and indexes? As oldsn3.db is significantly bigger I assume it has more records in these tables which could be affecting how the query is being run. Have you run ANALYZE on all the tables so you are sure you have up to date statistics for each table for the optimiser to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXPLAIN results explain. ***old*** has an **index** on the **timestamp** column (idx_logs_timestamp), ***new*** does not, and thus the variation.

Create an index on the **timestamp** column for the ***new*** database.

Comment: It is True EXPLAIN explains :). "Old" database is  created with an API on version x - 1 and "new" database is created with version x. It seams  that on new API version Logs.Timestamp is not INDEX so the query performs slower.
Thanks a lot for your time.